# jQuery - do something once AJAX complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a simple POST AJAX call - once this has complete I want to run a custom function - I tried .success() without any joy - can someone help me out?

```
jQuery.post('http://www.site.com/product/123/', jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize(), function() 
   // on success - do something here
});
```

Comment: What is the problem? The answer is in your question... To manage errors, use `$.ajax` instead. There is already a LOT of answers on the web..........

Comment: you're missing an opening curly brace `...').serialize(), function()` <--- here

Comment: @JoDev The OP could also make use of the [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) as part of a deferred object callback.

Comment: You can read up on this in jQuery documentation

Comment: Yes, you're right, and i can't change my comment now. But the main purpose of my comment was to say : Please, search before to POST. jQuery is very well documented, and all you need already is on the net at least 1000 places ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$.post(url, data, function () {
    alert("success");

    // Call the custom function here
    myFunction();
});
```

Or this:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post(url, data);

jqxhr.done(function () {
    alert("second success");
    // Call the custom function here
    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: +1 For deferred object handling...

Answer (score 3):

You can use any following callbacks based on your requirement in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
 .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Comment: +1 For deferred object handling...

Answer (score 1):

Try this out for your ajax call:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./WebServices/MethodName",
        data: "{someName: someValue}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var row = response.d;
            if (row.length > 0) {
                $.each(row, function (index, item) {
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#").html("No Rows Found");
            }
        },
        failure: function () {
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic usage of [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form id="foo">
 <label for="bar">A bar</label>
 <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<!-- The result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
/* Attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#foo").submit(function(event) {

/* Stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault();

/* Clear result div*/
$("#result").html('');

/* Get some values from elements on the page: */
var values = $(this).serialize();

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "post",
    data: values,
    success: function(){
        alert("success");
        $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
    }
  });
});
```